# Add into set until "full", then write to csv before filling set again

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am streaming a large amount of data that needs to be processed in chunks due to disconnections from source prior to completion.  I would like to add elements to a set until the `len(set)` is equal to some number, say 1000.  Once it reaches 1000, I would like to write the contents of that set into a csv file for storage.  Once written, I would like to empty the set and continue adding elements until the process is complete.  Because the end of the collection is likely not an even 1000 long set, I would also like a way to write the last set, whatever the size < 1000, to a csv.

I have tried the following:

```
import csv    
chunk = set()
for result in source:
    if len(chunk) <= 1000:
        chunk.add(element)
    elif len(chunk) == 1000:
        with open('file.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            for element in chunk:
                row = [element]
                writer.writerow(row)
    else:
        with open('file.csv', 'a') as csvfile:        
             writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
             for element in chunk:
                row = [element]
                writer.writerow(row)
```

My logic is that I'll add elements to the set until the `len(set)` is 1000, then I'll write it to a csv.  If neither conditions are true, I want to write it to the csv also.  Unfortunately, when executed, nothing is written and I believe it may have something to do with the potentially conflicting `if` and `else` statements.

Comment: The operating system almost certainly buffers writes to disk already; do you really need another explicit buffer in your code?

Comment: use `writer.writerows([element] for element in chunk)` that will be faster than a loop.

Comment: @chepner - The `set` discards duplicates, reducing file size.

Comment: You are not emptying your set after writing 1000 entries.

Comment: You should be getting an error because the very first `if len(chunk) <= 1000:` tries to add `element` but it's not defined yet.

Comment: @tdelaney I think that's more of a side effect than the main purpose, as you're still going to get duplicates that arrive in different chunks.

Comment: @chepner - yes, but if you are chunking a large data set and expect duplicates (especially duplicates clustered around each other) its a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move that last open outside of the loop. You have a couple of bugs so I did some tidying...

```
import csv

chunk = set()
for result in source:
    chunk.append(result)
    if len(chunk >= 1000):
        with open('file.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
            csv.writer(csvfile).writerows([element] for element in chunk)
            chunk = set()
if chunk:
    with open('file.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        csv.writer(csvfile).writerows([element] for element in chunk)
        chunk = set()
```

If you don't like writing the save logic twice, you can use two loops

```
import csv

chunk = set()
source_iter = iter(source)
have_data = True

while have_data:
    for result in source_iter:
        chunk.append(result)
        if len(chunk >= 1000):
            break
    else:
        have_data = False
    with open('file.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        csv.writer(csvfile).writerows([element] for element in chunk)
    chunk = set()
```